# How to download XLSX file through firefox using Selenium in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to download an xlsx file using the following code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "directory where to save data");
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/x-excel, application/x-msexcel, application/excel, application/vnd.ms-excel");

ob = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

But the test stops after displaying the download dialog box, and it is not downloading any file.

But if i try the same code for csv file by changing the mime type mentioned in the above code, then it works fine.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What other information should i mention? I tried to do it through wget, it will work, but i can not use that because the name of the file that will be downloaded is dynamic. It is generated on fly. Also I am working on UBUNTU so can not go for AutoIt.

Comment: Can somebody give an answer please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the above code I added following:

```
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",dest_path);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/xls;text/csv");
```

And now it is working fine. The MIME type for xlsx was not working properly so instead i tried to put the MIME type for xls file and now it is working fine. The XLSX file is getting downloaded automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MIME type for file that you are downloading is different (may be something like `application/force-download` ), 
as you have mentioned correct MIME type for xlsx - `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`.

Install "HTTPFox" Firefox plugin to record the traffic and check the actual MIME type captured in it. Once update with that MIME type, your code should work.